# Wordpress' comment_text() function adds <p> </p> automatically

Tags: php, html, wordpress

**the code is:**

```
<?php comment_text(); ?>
```

**it's output is:**

```
<p>Comment text</p>
```

**when I change it as:**

```
<p><?php comment_text(); ?></p>
```

**it's output becomes:**

```
<p></p>
<p>Comment text</p>
```

**the question is:** 
can I delete the `<p></p>` tag which becomes automatically? and add my `<p></p>` tag or add nothing?

Answer (score 4):

Use `get_comment_text()` to get the text without display:

```
<p><?php echo get_comment_text(); ?><p>
```

Then you can do whatever you want, like

```
<p class="myClass"><?php echo get_comment_text(); ?><p>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment_text

Comment: That's what I thought, but look at the function https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.4/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L981 Seems to use the same code, instead of `echo`.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong here, but look the line 159 https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.4/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L159 ... it sets `add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpautop', 30 );` for `comment_text` function, but not `get_comment_text`

Comment: Yeah. I think you're right :) I should have left my answer :)